# Jenkins batch command not using the system path

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

Jenkins has a feature called `Execute Windows Batch Command`,

But the command not using the system path,

So I have to use `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" push` instead of `git push`.

In fact, a lot of jobs work in `cmd.exe` will fail in Jenkins.

How to make `Execute Windows Batch Command` perform the same as `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure to run the Jenkins agent (or the main Jenkins controller if you have only one instance) with the right account.

It depends on how you have installed its agent and are running it:

- as a [`Windows Service`](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+as+a+Windows+service), in which case make sure it uses a user account.
  By default, it uses the [Windows system account](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/66743/system-account-in-windows), which means it has a different PATH/environment variables than your expected user on that agent.
- as a JNLP process the user on that agent runs directly, in which case it should benefit from the user PATH.